# Keep track of a .net application variable through different requests

Tags: c#, asp.net, application-state

In a .Net application when using C# I have to make an expensive call to get some data to a third party API, and depends on this one sometimes it's slower that I would like.

Thing is, that data will be accurate but I can calculate it with less precision on my own. So I was thinking how would I be able to let's say keep track of the average request time during the last 5 minutes and if it's greater than my threshold change to use my own implementation.

A sketch of the method would be something like this:

```
    public int GetMyData()
    {
        return isTooSlow() ? _ownImplementation.GetData() : thirdParty.GetData();
    }
```

Even if ideally I would like to be able to wrap the third party in an interface which mine would implement and change it on runtime that would be a nice to have.

But the mainquestion would be how to keep that state in memory. I can only think of using a static class and I have read about ApplicationState but not sure if any of those are the best approaches.

Besides, not for my small project but how would any of those solutions scale out?  If I had to think about several instances of my application running I think the only solution would be to use an external storage (redis or alike?) and query it when doing the check.

Sorry if the question is too generic but thought it was an interesting problem to solve and don't know exactly how to best approach it

Thanks

Comment: If you have your own implementation then why do you need to call the third party?  Or call the third party after hours and store the data somewhere so you can get to it faster.

Comment: The data are udated at "real time" on the third party, so I would like to call it every time unless it becomes close to unresponsive for the last minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would put the question of multiple application instances on the back burner. Not that it doesn't matter, but if you're programming against interfaces then at some point you could replace your implementation with something that's cached.

If you want average request times over a duration like five minutes then you'll need a list that ejects expired entries. Here's a stab at that:

```
internal class TimestampedEntry<T>
{
    internal DateTimeOffset Timestamp { get; private set; }
    internal T Value { get; private set; }

    internal TimestampedEntry(T value)
    {
        Timestamp = DateTimeOffset.Now;
        Value = value;
    }
}

public class ExpiringList<T> 
{
    private readonly List<TimestampedEntry<T>> _list = new List<TimestampedEntry<T>>();
    private readonly TimeSpan _expiration;

    public ExpiringList(TimeSpan expiration)
    {
        _expiration = expiration;
    }

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        lock (_list)
        {
          _list.Add(new TimestampedEntry<T>(item));              
        }
    }

    public IReadOnlyCollection<T> Read()
    {
        var cutoff = DateTimeOffset.Now - _expiration;
        TimestampedEntry<T>[] result;
        lock (_list)
        {
            result = _list.Where(item => item.Timestamp > cutoff).ToArray();
            _list.Clear();
            _list.AddRange(result);
        }
        return new ReadOnlyCollection<T>(result.Select(item => item.Value).ToList());
    }
}
```

That ensures that when you read from the list it only returns items stored within the specified interval and also deletes the rest. You could create an `ExpiringList<TimeSpan>`, add the elapsed time for each call, and then inspect the average as needed.

Where to store it? I'd put it in a class with a single instance. That could  be a singleton or a static class. I prefer using a dependency injection container that returns a single instance (like [Windsor's singleton lifestyle](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/lifestyles.md).) I don't like creating singletons. I'd rather create a "normal" class and then manage it to keep a single instance. DI containers like Windsor make that easy.

I think an important factor in an implementation like this is to keep the messy switching logic separate - hidden in some sort of factory as opposed to having an `if/then` with all the logic to check the average response times and call either API all in one big class.

For example, if you have an interface representing the call to get data, like `IMyDataProvider`, then you could define a factory like

```
interface IMyDataProviderFactory
{
    IMyDataProvider Create();
}
```

Your classes just depend on that factory interface. An class that implements `IMyDataProviderFactory` checks your average response times and returns either the implementation of `IMyDataProvider` that calls the external API or an implementation that uses your calculation.

That way the complexity of that logic stays separate from whatever classes depend on the APIs.

Windsor is good with those [abstract factories](http://scotthannen.org/blog/2016/02/23/abstract-factory-pattern.html) too. Other DI containers also make them easy, and this sort of functionality is built into ASP.NET Core. You weren't asking about dependency injection, but I recommend looking into it. It makes it easier to manage this sort of complexity and keep it maintainable.

---

Going back to multiple application instances and distributed caches - you can see how the factory pattern implementation makes this easier to manage. Let's say today this is one instance but tomorrow you want to share this data via a distributed cache. Where do you make that change? Most of the code that depends on this API won't need to change at all because it doesn't "know" about any of those implementation details. You would change the code that stores the timing of each API call and change the implementation of your factory.